# Excel Application-Defined Error When Selecting Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

A few months ago, I wrote a program in Excel using VBA, which worked fine. Today, I reopened the program and the code errored out on me, giving me an "application-defined or object-defined error" on me. This workbook is stored on a network drive that I do have read/write permissions to. I also tried working with a new copy of the workbook saved somewhere else on the drive, and also a copy saved on my desktop, each resulting in the same error.  Here is where the code stopped

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").ChartObjects("MainChart").Chart.ProtectData = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").ChartObjects("MainChart").Chart.ProtectFormatting = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").ChartObjects("VPricePerChart").Chart.ProtectData = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").ChartObjects("VPricePerChart").Chart.ProtectFormatting = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").ChartObjects("NewChart").Chart.ProtectData = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").ChartObjects("NewChart").Chart.ProtectFormatting = True
```

I know that I do not need to activate the sheet to change properties of specifically named objects, but I put that line in today after it quit working to see where the error occurred. The error occurs at the first line when I  use `Sheets("UI").Activate`. I tried running other procedures that contain `Sheets("UI")` and they all returned the same error. I checked to make sure the name of the worksheet had not changed, and it is still `UI`. The worksheet and the workbook are both unprotected and the worksheet is not hidden. I can run `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate` fine where `Data` is another sheet. I have also tried using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate` since `UI` is the first sheet in my workbook and that does not work.

The strangest part of this whole thing is that the exact same file opens perfectly fine, running all the code as written without causing any errors on my colleague's machine.

Any thoughts on why I cannot do anything that involves that sheet?

Comment: you need to change your `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").Activate` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").Select`

Comment: Is the code contained in the same workbook that you're processing, or is it in an Add-In or a Personal Workbook? I'd say the first step is to confirm that `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook you think it does. Add this line to check: `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name` (the results populate in the Immediate Window in the VBE). If that is correct, maybe add a loop such as: `For each sh in ThisWorkbook.Sheets` `Debug.Print sh.Name` `Next sh` and look for any anomalies.

Comment: Shai, activate vs select makes no difference. I don't actually want to activate or select the sheet, I simply put that in there to confirm that the chart object was not causing my problems. Trying to change any property or call any method of `Sheets("UI")` causes this error.

Comment: I printed the names of the worksheets: 

UI,
DropDown,
M-Code,
BlackBoard,
Database Mirror,
Data. 

They all appear as they should

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that your "UI" worksheet name has leading or trailing spaces?